# Overriding window.navigator.onLine to always be online

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript web app with numerous dependencies, some of which change their behaviour based on [`window.navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine). For example, some disable file transfer or retrying logic.

As described in the `onLine` docs,

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is **offline**.

However, my **app needs to work even when no network interface is attached.**

---

Another motivating example why one might want to override `onLine`:

MDN points out further situations in which `window.navigator.onLine` does not give the information one wants (here, false positives):

> You could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters that are always "connected."

---

For these reasons, and to not have to patch all dependency libraries that my app uses, **I wish to override `window.navigator.onLine` such that it always returns `true`.**

However, it seems to be a `readonly` property.

I already tried using [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), like so:

```js
if (window.navigator) {
  // `as any` to ignore `readonly` property
  (window.navigator as any) = new Proxy(window.navigator, {
    // See https://javascript.info/proxy
    get(target, prop, ...rest) {
      if (prop === "onLine") {
        return true;
      }
      return Reflect.get(target, prop, ...rest);
    },
  });
}
```

but on assignments of `window.navigator = ...` I get the error in e.g. Chrome 111:

```
Cannot set property navigator of #<Window> which has only a getter
```

Is there any way by which this can be achieved?

Comment: @mplungjan See _"to not have to patch all dependency libraries that my app uses"_ in the question description.

Comment: if those packages use ["offline" / "online" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine#listening_for_changes_in_network_status), you might be able to trick it by emitting that event ```window.dispatchEvent(new Event('offline'))```.

Comment: So you actually **want** that false-positive?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I quoted the MDN part on false positives just to give _another_ motivating example why one would might to implement their own logic for `onLine`. In general the problem is that apps care about "is my server reachable", but `navigator.onLine` doesn't really answer that question, yet libraries use it fo that.

Comment: I don't see how setting `onLine` to a constant `true` solves that problem - it just means the value will be false (wrong) more often than before. Rather report the issues to the library maintainers to get the bugs fixed

Comment: @Bergi I generally agree, `onLine` is a crude heuristic, and general-purpose libraries, should avoid hardcoding crude heuristic. But most libraries seem to think first about "the Internet", versus newer use cases that also work offline / on localhost; for Internet-only applications, the heuristic makes sense (e.g. it makes sense to not perma-retry if an Internet-only application is offline). So there'd be plenty convincing to do. To me the real bug is that the browser's API does not offer a way to control what `onLine` should be. Only the top-level application developer knows the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can patch it with a `getter` or writeable I will use the getter to ensure correctness even for injected browsers like `Avas`:
(this is a negative way if possible fix them instead of overwriting):

```js
Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'onLine', {
  get: () => true
})

console.log('navigator.onLine = %s', navigator.onLine)
```

**for those who want to test this code but don't want to shut down try the following offline offline code**

```js
Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'onLine', {
  get: () => false
})

console.log('navigator.onLine = %s', navigator.onLine)
```

Comment: Excellent, this seems to work. It can be tested e.g. with the Chrome Dev Tools, in the _Network_ tab, setting the Throttling dropdown to `Offline` (which usually sets `navigator.onLine = false`, but with your code, it stays `true`).

Comment: A stretch goal could be to implement `bogdanoff`'s comment to my question, and make it so that if somebody subscribes to the [`offline` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine#listening_for_changes_in_network_status), they never even get called. If that could be added to the answer, it would be even better. But I will already accept the answer, as my original question was only about the `onLine` property.

Comment: @nh2 you can easily and it by prototype